# Many to Many Data Binding in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to follow [Beth Massi's Many to Many Data Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/05/30/many-to-many-data-binding.aspx) tutorial. This tutorial makes the most sense to me as it follows my line of thinking. However, please give other options that you can think of.

I am trying to replicate the tutorial's results with a slighly different dataset using a WPF UI and C# in the code-behind.

You can see my dataset at https://i.stack.imgur.com/czrf5.png

I have successfully built the UI as per the tutorial but I left the datagrid that is bound to the Drawings_Wires table in for the time being. My (VS 2013 generated) XAML is:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdventureWorksOrdersViewer"        x:Class="AdventureWorksOrdersViewer.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TESTDataSet x:Key="tESTDataSet"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="drawingsViewSource" Source="{Binding Drawings, Source={StaticResource tESTDataSet}}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="drawingsDrawings_WiresViewSource" Source="{Binding FK_DWGAutoKey, Source={StaticResource drawingsViewSource}}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="wiresViewSource" Source="{Binding Wires, Source={StaticResource tESTDataSet}}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource drawingsViewSource}" >

        <DataGrid x:Name="drawingsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="0,0,0,570" ItemsSource="{Binding}" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dWG_Auto_KeyColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True" Header="DWG Auto Key" Binding="{Binding DWG_Auto_Key}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dWG_NumberColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="DWG Number" Binding="{Binding DWG_Number}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="titleColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="revisionColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Revision" Binding="{Binding Revision}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="wiresDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource wiresViewSource}}" Margin="0,489,0,67" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wire_Auto_IDColumn1" Binding="{Binding Wire_Auto_ID}" Header="Wire Auto ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wireCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding WireCode}" Header="Wire Code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wireLengthColumn" Binding="{Binding WireLength}" Header="Wire Length" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wireTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding WireType}" Header="Wire Type" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="drawings_WiresDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource drawingsDrawings_WiresViewSource}}" Margin="58,233,334,337" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dWG_Auto_KeyColumn1" Binding="{Binding DWG_Auto_Key}" Header="DWG Auto Key" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wire_Auto_IDColumn" Binding="{Binding Wire_Auto_ID}" Header="Wire Auto ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My issue is how to fire an event in C# when the drawingsDrawings_WiresViewSource Collection changes similar to the OrderDetailBindingSource.ListChanged event that Beth used in her tutorial.

I not even sure where to begin as I still new to WPF and C#. I tried adding the following lines to the Window_Loaded event, but it didn't do anything. I'll admit though that I was being hopeful and didn't really expect it to work.

```
drawingsDrawings_WiresViewSource.View.CollectionChanged += View_CollectionChanged;

void View_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

If there is anyone out there who is willing to take some time to enlighten me, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

theoleric

Comment: would you mind sharing what you've tried so far?